# Assigning a string to a pointer in a struct

Tags: c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
        char *forename;
        char *surname;
        int age;
};

void change_struct(struct Person *person, char *forename, char *surname,
                int age);
void print_struct(struct Person *person);

int main(void)
{
        struct Person person1;
        person1.forename = malloc((strlen("Max") + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!person1.forename) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(person1.forename, "Max");
        person1.surname = malloc((strlen("Mustermann") + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!person1.surname) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(person1.surname, "Mustermann");
        person1.age = 35;

        print_struct(&person1);

        change_struct(&person1, "Hans", "Bauer", 45);

        print_struct(&person1);

        free(person1.forename);
        free(person1.surname);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void change_struct(struct Person *person, char *forename, char *surname,
                int age)
{
        person->forename = realloc(person->forename,
                                   (strlen(forename) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!person->forename) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(person->forename, forename);
        person->surname = realloc(person->surname,
                                  (strlen(surname) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!person->surname) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(person->surname, surname);
        person->age = age;
}

void print_struct(struct Person *person)
{
        printf("%s\n", person->forename);
        printf("%s\n", person->surname);
        printf("%d\n", person->age);
}
```

When assigning a string to a pointer in a `struct` is it well-defined behaviour if I would do

```
person1.forename = "Max";
person1.surname = "Mustermann";
```

in `main()` initially instead of using `malloc()` and `strcpy()`?

*NOTE: (Of course in this specific case I would need to also change the `realloc()` calls in `change_struct()` since it is undefined behaviour when `realloc()` receives a non- `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` created pointer.)*

If dynamic memory allocation should be required could you give an explanation why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you don't want to modify the contents,

```
person1.forename = "Max";
person1.surname = "Mustermann";
```

are perfectly valid.

In this case, `person1.forename` will be a pointer to the *string literal* and any attempt to modify the contents will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

1. for `print_struct()` function, you don't need to pass a pointer to the structure.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to produce `1` in `C`. Using it for multiplication (to get the size in `malloc()`)is redundant, can be omitted easily.

Comment: I don't know but I am under the impression that `C` is quite a harsh tag by now in terms of down- and upvotes. (Not trying to start a discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

```
person1.forename = "Max";
person1.surname = "Mustermann";
```

You are making your pointers point to string literals , so make a note that string literls are read-only. So once you have the above initialization you can't modify the string the pointer is pointing to which is not the case with the memory allocated by `malloc()` and family functions.

Since you are allocating memory explicitly you can use it to read and write.So you need dynamic memory allocation here if you wish to modify the string the pointers are pointing to

Answer (score 1):

`"Max"` is a null-terminated read-only string literal in C; using a `const char*` to point to the first character is well-defined and idiomatic.

You ought to change the types of your structure elements to `const char*` if you are going to populate it in such a manner as the behaviour on amending a read-only literal is *undefined*.

Of course, you can set `forename` &c. to point to another character string.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad approach. In this case you may not apply function `realloc` inside function `change_struct` because string literals have static storage duration. They are not allocated dynamically

This function is a general-purpose function and it can accept arguments for parameters `forename` and `surname` of various kind not only string literals.

For example the function can be called like

```
char name[] = "Hans";

change_struct(&person1, name, "Bauer", 45);
```

Or even like

```
if ( some_condition )
{
    char name[] = "Hans";

    change_struct(&person1, name, "Bauer", 45);
}
```

In this case any changing of `name` will also change the string pointed to by data member `forename` of an object of the type of the structure. Moreover if array `name` will be defined in some local scope as it is shown in the example with the if statement then the pointer will be even invalid.